# multiple venn diagram in one figure

Tags: r

I am looking to find a way to be able to make such a figure

[image]

I need to have Venn diagram for pairwise and I know that I can do each at the time like this

```
grid.newpage()
draw.pairwise.venn(22, 20, 11, category = c("Dog People", "Cat People"), lty = rep("blank", 
    2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0, 
    0), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
```

Now lets say I have 6 sets as follows, can someone comment?

```
draw.pairwise.venn(22, 20, 11)
draw.pairwise.venn(33, 55, 5)
draw.pairwise.venn(44, 22, 2)
draw.pairwise.venn(330, 550, 50)
draw.pairwise.venn(2200, 400, 0)
draw.pairwise.venn(25, 33, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this at a fairly low level within the `grid` framework by defining the 6 viewports in a list, the arguments for the diagrams in a list, and a function that uses these arguments to draw a diagram in each viewport. Then just `Map` them together:

```r
library(grid)
library(VennDiagram)

vps <- lapply(1:6, function(x) viewport(x = 0.75 - (x %% 2)/2,
                                 y = 1/6 + ((x - 1) %/% 2)/3,
                                 width = 0.5,
                                 height = 1/3))

venns <- list(c(22, 20, 11),
              c(33, 55, 5),
              c(44, 22, 2),
              c(330, 550, 50),
              c(2200, 400, 0),
              c(25, 33, 0))

labels <- paste("label", 1:6)

func <- function(vp, venn, lab) {
  pushViewport(vp)
  draw.pairwise.venn(venn[1], venn[2], venn[3],
                     category = c("Dog People", "Cat People"), 
                     lty = rep("blank", 2), ext.text = FALSE,
                     fill = c("light blue", "pink"), 
                     alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,  0), 
                     cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
  grid.draw(textGrob(lab, 0.8, 0.1, gp = gpar(fontface = 2)))
  popViewport()
}

grid.newpage()

Map(func, vp = vps, venn = venns, lab = labels)
```

[image]

**Edit**

Example with 9 viewports:

```r
vps <- lapply(1:9, function(x) viewport(x = 1/6 + ((x - 1) %% 3)/3,
                                 y = 1/6 + ((x - 1) %/% 3)/3,
                                 width = 1/3,
                                 height = 1/3))

venns <- list(c(22, 20, 11),
              c(33, 55, 5),
              c(44, 22, 2),
              c(330, 550, 50),
              c(2200, 400, 0),
              c(25, 33, 0),
              c(22, 20, 11),
              c(33, 55, 5),
              c(44, 22, 2))

labels <- paste("label", 1:9)


grid.newpage()

Map(func, vp = vps, venn = venns, lab = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to get rid of that line things for one of them? also being able to put a word next to each graph

Comment: @nik I've never used `VennDiagram` before, but according to the docs, the "line thing" is turned off using the ext.text parameter. There doesn't seem to be an option to add an arbitrary label, but of course we can draw this in easily enough. Please see my update.

Comment: I already liked your answer, just one small thing and I accept your answer. if the number becomes 9, then it won't be plotting it . I know it is something to do with `vps` but I have changed as many numbers as there is and I still could not get it right. would you please explain that section ? so that it is amendable ?

Comment: @nic see my update. The lapply is just to make multiple viewport creation less repetitive. You can do it by hand too : `vps <- list(viewport(1/6, 1/6, 1/3, 1/3), viewport(3/6, 1/6, 1/3, 1/3), viewport(5/6, 1/6, 1/3, 1/3))` etc